# R loop to approximate square root of a positive real number with Newton's method

Tags: r, loops, repeat, newtons-method

I am new to R and I'm working on a homework question which asks me to use a `repeat` loop using [Newton's method for square root approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number). Here is what I have so far:

```
x = 2
a = 10
tol = 1e-04
repeat {
  (abs(x^2 - a) > tol)
  (x = 0.5 * (a/x + x))
  if (all.equal(x^2, a)) {
    break
  }
}
```

But I am getting some error message plus a wrong answer. In the end, `a` should nearly equal `x ^ 2` but it doesn't yet. I know there is something wrong with the `all.equal` portion, but I'm trying to figure out how to break the loop once they are close enough.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: `if` needs a logical input. `all.equal` does not (necessarily) output a logical value. For example `all.equal(1, 2)`.

Comment: I believe your implementation of the algorithm is wrong but if it were right, you should use `if (isTRUE(all.equal(x^2, a)))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `all.equal` at all.

```
## trying to find `sqrt(10)`
x <- 2
a <- 10
tol <- 1e-10
repeat{
  x <- 0.5 * (a / x + x)
  if (abs(x * x - a) < tol) break
  }
x
#[1] 3.162278
```